# Is the splitting field of some polynomials the same as $f(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) $where $\alpha_i$ are all the zeroes.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

So I'm starting galois theory and this book has the following theorem:

> A field $E$, where $F\leq E \leq \bar F$, is a splitting field over $F$ if and only if every automorphism of $\bar F$ leaving $F$ fixed maps $E$ onto itself and thus induces and automorphism of $E$ leaving $F$ fixed.

Here's a short proof synopsis of the $\Rightarrow$ direction.

We let E be a splitting field of a set of polynomials, and considering the set $S$ which contains the finite sums and finite products of all elements of the form $g(a_j)= a_0+a_1\alpha_j+...+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n_j-1}$ where $\alpha_j$ is a zero of one of our polynomials and $a_k \in F$ and then we prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $E$ and that $S=E$. Using that we see that the values of any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\bar F$ leaving $F$ fixed is completely determined by the values of $\sigma(\alpha_i)$ and using some other theroems from different chapters we show that $\sigma$ induces an automorphism on $E$.

My question is:

why is the set $S$ different from $F(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)$ where $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ are all the zeroes, and if it isn't why did we have to prove all those stuff about $S$

Comment: It looks like you are proving that $S = F(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$. There is some work involved because it is not immediately clear that the set $S$ is actually a field. (I am not quite sure I understand your question correctly, it depends a little on what you mean by "all those stuff"...)

Comment: Well the book clearly proved that $S$ is a field and in fact $ S=E$ but my question is why do we need that? Can't we just use $F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and show that it must equal $E$ since we already know that it is a field.

Comment: Usually $F(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ is defined as the smallest subfield of $\bar{F}$ containing $F$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$. How are you directly from this definition concluding that the automorphism fixing $F$ also fixes $E$?

Comment: Well $E$ just has the same definition as $F(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n)$ So the we immediately know that the value of $\sigma$ for element of $E$ is determined by the values of $\sigma(\alpha _j)$ from there we have that $\sigma(\alpha_j)$ must be a zero of $irr(\alpha_j,F)$. So $irr(\alpha_j,F)$ divides the $f_i(x)$ for which $f_i(\alpha_j)$, so $\sigma (\alpha_j)\in E$ from there it is pretty straightforward